# How to convert DOS-time to UNIX time in PHP?

Tags: php, unix, dos

I was recently searching for a function to convert DOS time (date and time coded into a 4 byte word) into UNIX time.  The only function I could find was in Java, so here is the code converted to PHP.  If anyone has a better solution, please post it here.

```
function dosToUnixTime($dosTime) {
    $date = mktime(
        (($dosTime >> 11) & 0x1f), // hours
        (($dosTime >> 5) & 0x3f),  // minutes
        (($dosTime << 1) & 0x3e),  // seconds
        ((($dosTime >> 21) & 0x0f) - 1),   // month
        (($dosTime >> 16) & 0x1f),         // day
        ((($dosTime >> 25) & 0x7f) + 1980) // year
    );
    return $date;
}
```

Comment: That is some good stuff, you basically [answered your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) which is what future readers will appreciate! SO provides a way to 'answer your own question Q&A style' which is the link in my comment, if you have more of this coming up I would consider reading the format for this but please do keep posting these snippets (and perhaps an explanation too for those with less experience such as myself) :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a code review.